# how to stop the infinite loop in my programme

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I wrote the following program to recognize the negative and positive numbers, but I do not know why it gets stuck in an infinite loop?
I would appreciate it if anyone helps me!!!

```
# negative and positive numbers

num = input('please enter a number:')
while True: 
    num = int(num)
    if num < 0:
        print('your num is negative!')
    elif num == 0:
        print('your num is zero!')
    else:
        print('your num is positive!')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to include a condition to break out of the loop.

Comment: "but I do not know why it gets stuck in an infinite loop?" In your own words, what do you think "while True:` means? What do you think should happen instead, and why do you think so? (For example, are you expecting the user to be asked for a number again? if so, why? Hint: if you want something to happen multiple times in a program, should it be inside a loop, or outside of all loop? What line in your code asks the user for a number? Is that inside the loop, or outside?)

Comment: @CodyGray that question cannot work as a duplicate target, because it was originally caused by a typo (incorrect indentation that was previously incorrectly "fixed" by another editor, making the problem not reproducible instead); the answers there address the debugging problem, and do not address the question in the title (perhaps because all parties thought it was trivial). (Also, perhaps this helps you understand why I take a broader interpretation of "caused by a typo" than you do.)

Comment: (Meanwhile, the problem here was caused by a **different** logical error. The indentation error in the other question *could* be interpreted as instead having a mistaken idea about how the code should be structured, rather than simply failing to express that intent.)

Comment: Surely there is a question on Stack Overflow describing how to use "break" to break out of a `while` loop, @KarlKnechtel. Could you find that one and close this accordingly, please? (This isn't a typo, nor is it unclear. It is, however, a common beginner question, and it should almost certainly be closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: It's unclear in that the thought process behind consciously writing `while True:` and then asking "I do not know why it gets stuck in an infinite loop?" cannot be fathomed. It would at least need to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

The code gets stuck in an infinite loop because you have used `while True`.

Do this instead,

```
num = int(input('please enter a number:'))

if num < 0:
    print('your num is negative!')
elif num == 0:
    print('your num is zero!')
else:
    print('your num is positive!')
```

To break out of an infinite loop you can use the `break` keyword.

Using `break` -

```
num=input('please enter a number:')
while True: 
    num = int(num)
    if num < 0:
        print('your num is negative!')
        break
    elif num == 0:
        print('your num is zero!')
        break
    else:
        print('your num is positive!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

you will be in the loop till the while condition is true and you have stated it true.. so it goes into an infinite loop.

```
num = input('please enter a number:')
while True: 
    num = int(num)
    if num < 0:
        print('your num is negative!')
        break
    elif num == 0:
        print('your num is zero!')
        break
    else:
        print('your num is positive!')
        break
```

Add break statement

or

```
num = int(input('please enter a number:'))

if num < 0:
    print('your num is negative!')
elif num == 0:
    print('your num is zero!')
else:
    print('your num is positive!')
```

Try avoiding using while True. It may create the issue of infinite loop if we forget to add break statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask the user for a number repeatedly. You need to add a condition in the `while` loop to break it. For example, you can check if the user enters "stop" to break the loop.

```
while (True):
  # Read the user input.
  numStr = input('Please, enter a number: ')

  # Check if the user enters "stop".
  if (numStr == "stop"):
    break
  else:
    # Convert the user string input to float to accept any digit.
    num = float(numStr)

    if (num < 0):
      print('Your num is negative!')
    elif (num == 0):
      print('Your num is zero!')
    else:
      print('Your num is positive!')
```

If you want to ask the use for a number only once. You need to remove the `while` loop.

```
# Read the user input.
numStr = input('Please, enter a number: ')

# Convert the user string input to float to accept any digit.
num = float(numStr)

# Check the number: +ve, 0, -ve.
if (num < 0):
  print('Your num is negative!')
elif (num == 0):
  print('Your num is zero!')
else:
  print('Your num is positive!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't breaking the while loop, that's why its program stucked in infinite loop.
You can use this

```
# negative and positive numbers
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input('please enter a number:'))
        if num < 0:
            print('your num is negative!')
        elif num == 0:
            print('your num is zero!')
        elif num > 0:
            print('your num is positive!')
        choice = input("Do you want to check other number. press y|n")
        if choice == "n":
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please give integer value only")
```

You can look into https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exception-handling/

---

Happy coding :)

---

Comment: This is a duplicate of an of existing answer, by `Zero`. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.